# Regex for Persian with numbers and words

Tags: javascript, java, regex

How can I get Persian number in below string in original format (for example `٠٠:٥٣`).

```
+بیسبب+
یبسب به یبیسب ٩٥٧,٠٩٠*+ ذرزذر  بللبل ٢٤٧,٠٠٠ 
بسبس: ٩٥٧,٠٩٠
بسبس: ٩٥٧,٠٩٠
٠٠:٥٣ ٩٧,٠٦,٠٧
```

Also I need to get Persian words. 
I wrote this regex but it's not correct.

```
([\d{\u0660-\u0669}\,])+
```

Comment: If you think someone who doesn’t know Persian can help, you may want to explain for those of us who cannot tell a Persian digit when we see one.

Comment: Your question is not completely clear. What should be the final output for that string? I speak Persian and that string is meaningless for me.

Comment: Your question is tagged with both Java and JavaScript, but couldn’t it be that the answers will be different for the two languages?

Comment: In Java regex I believe `\d` captures an ASCII digit only, 0 through 9. `\d{6,9}` is supposed to capture 6 through 9 digits. I don’t believe you can put Unicode escapes instead of the numbers. Finally, `\,` does not have a specific meaning.

Comment: Here's a tiny Java sample that you can play with. It appears to work. You can use the posted answer to fiddle with the character ranges: https://ideone.com/pGorwZ

Answer (score 0):

To capture the numbers, you can either use:

```
([\u0660-\u0669\,]+)
```

Or you can enumerate all the digits if you want your code to be more understandable:

```
([٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩\,]+)
```

This will capture only the numbers.

For Persian script, I don't really know what are the Persian characters used, so I will take the range from \u0600 to \u065F, then from \u066E to \u06D5

[image: Arabic charsets]

```
([\u0600-\u065F\u066E-\u06D5]+)
```